# How to get id from mysql to modal?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, modal-dialog

I am having a problem about getting id from mysql table to modal.
I got a datatable that contain data from mysql table. i put a "UPDATE" button to edit data. UPDATE button opens modal in same page. The button code is ;

```
<a data-toggle='modal' class='btn btn-success btn-setting' href='#myModal1'>UPDATE</a>
```

It works perfectly and opens modal very well. But the problem starts from there. 
I need to target and post the id to modal content. To do this I have to do something like `**href='something.php?id={id}'**`

I have `href='#myModal1'>` so I couldn't do it.

**What I have tried ?**

I have tried `**href='#myModal1?kid={$list["kid"]}'**` 
When I mouse over the button I can see that it is getting the id but when I click the button the modal is not opening. 
Also I have tried to search google. I think lots of people are fixing this with javascript which I dont know :) Any help will be awesome. Thanks !

Comment: pass the value in `onclick` event using a function. And in function, populate the control with that value

Comment: Try a hidden field in your model div and set id then you can get on post also?

Comment: Add new attribute to anchor tag, data-id="update-id". Then get it using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Create one class (any class name). For ex, i created '`UpdateButton`' in `<a>` tag.
Create one '`data-OrderID`' (or any name). For ex, i created '`data-OrderID`' in `<a>` tag. Pass value of your ID in this attribute. Use in `<script>` tag below.

```
<a href='#myModal1' class='btn btn-success btn-setting UpdateButton' data-OrderID="<?echo $YourIdHere;?>"  data-toggle='modal'>
    UPDATE
</a>
```

Now, in `<script>` tag, i used 'UpdateButton' class to call modal. And, '`data-OrderID`' to pass value to `something.php` page

```
<script>
    $('.UpdateButton').click(function(){
        var Id=$(this).attr('data-OrderID');
        $.ajax({url:"something.php?Id="+Id,cache:false,success:function(result){
            $(".modal-content").html(result);
        }});
    });
</script>
```

**something.php** (modal)

```
<?
echo $Id = $_GET['Id'];
?>
```

It works for me. Hope for you too.

Check [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043115/passing-data-via-modal-bootstrap-and-getting-php-variable/33043821#33043821) for more info.

Comment: I would say better use `.data()` instead `.attr()`, purpose of `data-attribute` dies if you still use `.attr()` so better is this  `var Id=$(this).data('OrderID');`

Comment: tryed all ways that you explained. Still no luck. I think i m something doing wrong :/

Comment: Hi @Fxx. I've answered this type of questions a lot. Even, this question is my favourite. I'm in shock, why it is not working. But, unfortunately this code didn't helped you. I'm really sorry.

Comment: i found the solution with diffrent way @Nana Partykar. it is working very well now. Thanks for trying to help ! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Add a data attribute in html as bellow I used "data-exid"

```
<a data-toggle='modal' data-exid='[YOUR ID]' class='btn btn-success btn-setting' href='#myModal1'>UPDATE</a>
```

and try bellow code for model box start event

```
jQuery('#myModal1').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
var button = jQuery(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
var exId = button.data('exid') // Extract info from data-* attributes
// If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
// Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or 0other methods instead.

/*Add this line in local*/
var modal = jQuery(this)
modal.find('#logId').val(-1)
modal.find('#logId').val(exId)});
```

Here "#logId" is an id of hidden box in a model

Comment: no need to create 2 variables `var button` & `var exId`, it can be done with one variable like this `var exId = jQuery(event.relatedTarget).data('exid')`