# How to pass current row value in modal?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am perfoming PHP CRUD operations on a table. When i click the edit button rather then taking it to a new page i want to show the values in a modal. I want the value's to be displayed in the modal's form. I have created a modal but i am unable to think of an logic to pass the values of the row in which the edit button was clicked. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Table:**

```
<table class="table datatable-basic table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class='active'>
            <th><b>S.No.</b></th>
            <th><b>Name</b></th>
            <th><b>Mobile Number</b></th>
            <th><b>Password</b></th>
            <th><b>Actions</b></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php 

            $sql="SELECT * from users ORDER BY name ASC" ; 
            $c = 1;
            $results = $result->query($sql);
            while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) 
            { 
             echo '<tr style="font-weight:normal;">'; 
             echo "<td>$c</td>"; 
             echo "<td>{$row['name']}</td>"; 
             echo "<td>{$row['username']}</td>"; 
             echo "<td>{$row['pass']}</td>"; 

             echo "<td class='text-center'><ul class='icons-list'><a href='#' style='color:#000;'><i class='icon-pencil5' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal_edit'
             data-popup='tooltip' title='Edit' data-container='body'></i></a>

             <a href='delete.php?teacherid={$row['username']}' style='color:#000;'><i class='icon-cross2' data-popup='tooltip' title='Delete' 
             data-container='body'></i></a></ul></td>"; 
             echo '</tr>';
               ++$c; 
            } 
        ?>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

My **Modal** is like this:-

```
<div id="modal_edit" class="modal fade" style="font-weight: normal;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h5 class="modal-title">Add Teacher</h5>
        </div>

        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Full Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Mobile Number</label>
                            <input type="text" name="mobno" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Kushal.. you know very well that without sharing code, no one can help you. So, Please share your code which you tried. Because, we are not going to assume your code.

Comment: @ThinkTank As i said in description i am unable to think of an logic. Your help would be very useful.

Comment: Where is your code from where you are passing value to modal. Please share.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass $\_GET variables from a link to a bootstrapmodal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodal)

Comment: @NanaPartykar I have posted the modal code but i can't think of a way to pass the values.

Comment: Ok. No Problem. But, please show code where you are planning to call modal. It's meaningful.

Comment: @NanaPartykar Updated with table code.

Comment: Please have a look to my answer. And. respond me back @KushalSrivastava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
    .
    .
    echo "<td class='text-center'>
            <ul class='icons-list'>
                <a href='#modal_edit' class='modalButton' style='color:#000;' data-teacherid='{$row['username']}' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal_edit' data-popup='tooltip' title='Edit' data-container='body'>
                    <i class='icon-pencil5'></i>
                </a>";

    echo "<a href='delete.php?teacherid={$row['username']}' style='color:#000;'><i class='icon-cross2' data-popup='tooltip' title='Delete' 
    data-container='body'></i></a></ul></td>"; 
    echo '</tr>';
    ++$c; 
} 
?>
```

Place this code somewhere, but in the same page.

```
<div id="modal_edit" class="modal fade" style="font-weight: normal;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">

          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $('.modalButton').click(function(){
        var teacherid = $(this).attr('data-teacherid');
        $.ajax({url:"ajax_modal_edit.php?teacherid="+teacherid,cache:false,success:function(result){
            $(".modal-content").html(result);
        }});
    });
</script>
```

Create a page name **ajax_modal_edit.php** (If you are looking to change this page name. Change in `<script></script>` tag too. Both are related.)

**ajax_modal_edit.php**

```
<?php
$teacherid = $_GET['teacherid'];

// Use this `$teacherid` in query to get all required/appropriate field
?>

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h5 class="modal-title">Add Teacher <?php echo $teacherid;?></h5>
</div>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label>Full Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label>Mobile Number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="mobno" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

For more info, check [Passing data via Modal Bootstrap and getting php variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043115/passing-data-via-modal-bootstrap-and-getting-php-variable/33043821#33043821)

Comment: What problem you are facing @KushalSrivastava. Cross check once again. It should come.

Comment: Thank you @Nana Partykar it worked i placed the script before jquery that is why it was not working.

Comment: If you think this answer helped you. Then, Please tick this answer as it will help other user to find it easily. @KushalSrivastava `:D` *Glad To Help* `:)` *Achha Hain..!!*

Comment: And, if you don't know how to tick answer, you can have a look here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . Thanks @KushalSrivastava